# Can't Uninstall Compass

Tags: ruby, console, compass-sass

I'm trying to uninstall Compass, so I ran `sudo gem uninstall compass` and it seemed to go through the uninstall process normally. If I try running `sudo gem uninstall compass` again it just gives me a new command line.

However, if I run `compass -v`, it still returns version information:

```
Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)
Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
```

So is Compass *really* uninstalled? If not, how do I uninstall it completely?

Comment: If you ask it `gem which compass` and go there and remove that gem, you should find joy.  However, it seems like you have some issues.  Perhaps you are using some kind of Ruby environment manager, such as `rbenv`, `chruby` or `RVM`?  Or have used one of them.  In that case, you may need to not use `sudo` to remove the gem.  You are removing the system installed gem, but not the user space installed gem.  What does `echo $GEM_PATH` give you at the command line?

Comment: removing `sudo` seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask it `gem which compass` and go there and remove that gem (manually), you should find joy. However, it seems like you have some issues. Perhaps you are using some kind of Ruby environment manager, such as `rbenv`, `chruby` or `RVM`? Or have used one of them. In that case, you may need to not use sudo to remove the gem. (automated, and recommended).

You are attempting to remove the system installed gem, but not the user space installed gem.